# Sending meeting invitation using PHPMailer

Tags: php, outlook, phpmailer, icalendar

I am trying to send meeting invitations to customers using PHPMailer. The *.ics files are generated dynamically using PHP (they aren't stored on the file system).

My iCalendar files look like the following:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//ABC Corporation//Productname//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
SEQUENCE:0
LAST-MODIFIED:20131023T120039ZUID:20131023T120039-29881-www.host.com
DTSTAMP:20131023T120039Z
DTSTART:20131102T083000Z
DTEND:20131102T084500Z
LOCATION:event location
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=us-en:topic of the meeting 
DESCRIPTION: further information
ORGANIZER; CN="Organizer":mailto:organizer@host.com
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-P1D
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Unfortunately, I just managed to add the *.ics file as an attachment yet.

```
$icalendar = new ICalendar();
$mail->AddStringAttachment($icalendar->genICalendar(), "meeting.ics", "base64", "text/calendar");
```

How can I send it as an outlook/gmail-styled invitation like the following?
[image]

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

here is my solution for outlook  i use it in an webproject since 2 Years

```
static $iCalContentType = "text/calendar";
    static $iCalContentDisposition = "inline; filename=calendar.vcs";
    static $iCalTmpl = "
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:MyApp
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN=\"AppNameMailer\":mailto:automail@mydomain.com
SUMMARY: __summary__
DESCRIPTION: \"__description__\"
COMMENT: none
DTSTART:__start__
DTEND:__end__
UID: __id__-AppName
SEQUENCE:__seq__
DTSTAMP:__now__
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
TRANSP:OPAQUE
LOCATION:
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT25M
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
";
```

Works fine for me ! 
I just replace the `__*__` Markers (take care there are no `"` ).

Ah and the correct time encoding is vital as far as i remember - has to be iso8601 (ending with `Z`)

hope it helps...

Comment: thanks for your reply! How do I have to set the content-type and content-disposition correctly in PHPMailer?